# Sharing unit tests with dependencies in maven project

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have maven project with module A and module B which depends on module A.
For example I have abstract unit test in module A and I want to use this unit test in unit tests for module B.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `<goal>test-jar</goal>` execution of the `maven-jar-plugin` to make the Jar file, then simpy include it as a dependency in your other project, by adding `<type>` and `<scope>` attributes in the definition of that dependency:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, declare a dependency in Module B for Module A following [this guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html).

Comment: I am not sure that src/test/java is packaged as part of Maven-distributed jars.

Comment: The test-jar goal of the maven-jar-plugin will package the test-classes into a jar. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html